# Regex to omit/exclude first line

Tags: regex

I need a regex code in order to get all lines from a text, except the first one.
I tried some approaches but got no results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: What language is your code in? Different languages have different regex flavours

Comment: Without the language we can't help you.

Comment: I just hope it's not Javascript. They don't support `look-behind`.

Comment: Why don't you just split the input into an array of lines and then delete the first element? Why use a regular expression?

Comment: I'm sorry. There's no specific language. I'll use it on a OCR software called Teleform (from HP). I think it uses same regex present in VBscript.

Comment: If that's the case you are looking for Perl's Regex.

Answer (score 5):

With the small amount of information you've given, I'll make a guess and say that what you wan't is:

```
(?<=\n).*(?=\n)
```

But if the last line is terminated by a line feed, you may want

```
(?<=\n).*(?=\n[^\n]*?\n)
```

Now, this won't work in javascript, therefore *we* (as said in comments) need to know language/environment.

In JS you could use

```
\n(.*)(?=\n)
```

or

```
\n(.*)(?=\n[^\n]*?\n)
```

and get the result of the first capture group.

Hope this helps.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

A `look-behind` for newline and matching `everything` after it does the job.

**Regex:** `(?<=[\n\r]).*`

**Explanation:** This checks if everything `.*` is preceded by a newline checked by `positive look-behind` `(?<=[\n\r])`, which will be first found after first line.

Thus excluding the first line from search and matching everything after it.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sM7zO1/1)**

Answer (score 0):

In php flavor regex

```
^.*\n\K
```

where

`^`     start of line

`.`     match any char except linefeed

`*`     do the above match unlimited times

`\n`    match the line feed
`\K`    reset where are you in the string, consumed to this point,

with `\m`, this will repeat on next line

with `\g`, the search will keep repeating past next line